# I got this error message. I have never seen it before

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
  x, y = 10, 100

if (x < y): 
  st('x is less than y')

print(st)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

[pyflakes] local variable 'x' is assigned to but never used
[pyflakes] local variable 'y' is assigned to but never used

I got this message on line 2 of the code and I have no idea on what to do. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what was the point of assigning to `x` and `y` if those values will never be used?  Your `if (x < y)` is outside the function, and would be accessing non-existent global variables of the same name - entirely unrelated to the local variables inside `main()`.

Comment: I got this from Joe Marini's course.

Comment: What is `st`? Why are you trying to call it on one line and then print it on another? Also, the indentation looks completely messed up.

Comment: It was my first time doing functions. I apologise.

Comment: No problem. Everyone has no start from scratch. Just know that Stack Overflow isn't really the website you need. There are much better websites that offer tutorials and help for new programmers. Come back when you have some coding under your belt. Stack Overflow will still be here and it is a great place to read other people's questions and learn interesting ways to handle them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question got down-voted because of a (perceived) lack of research on your part, refer to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). If you need pointers for tutorials and information on Python, check out the [`python` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).

Comment: Also don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to the answer) when it answers your question. In this way, your question won't show up as unanswered in the searches anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. Your indentations are off, and the st command made no sense.

```
def main():
    x, y = 10, 100
    if (x < y): 
        st = 'x is less than y'
        print(st)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.